# Importing a Freebsd ZFS pool into Ubuntu 16.04 (shows up as a binary file)

Tags: zfs

I’ve been running FreeBSD 9.1 now for a while but for different reasons I would like to migrate to Ubuntu.

However, I have a few ZFS pools that I would like to bring with me…

I exported one of them (just to try) from FreeBSD (`zpool export backup`) and tried to import it in Ubuntu (`sudo zpool import backup`).
The original mount point was on /backup/ and it shows up in the “new” backup folder I created on the Ubuntu system. However, when viewing the disk it shows up as a binary file and not as a file system.
I can’t `cd` into the tree structure. I can however use `ls –l` to find my way into the tree structure and then `cp` files out of there.

Any ideas?